# Post-installation process of PostgreSQL 8.4 in FreeBSD?

Tags: installation, freebsd, postgresql, console, process

I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4 with `pkg_add -r postgres84-server`.
I added 'postgresql_enable="YES"`to`/etc/rc.conf`, and executed`/usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql initdb`.

And when I run `psql` to start, it printed these errors:

```
%psql
psql: FATAL:  database "eonil" does not exist
%psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
%psql -U psql
psql: FATAL:  database "psql" does not exist
%psql -U pgsql
psql: FATAL:  database "pgsql" does not exist
%sudo psql 
psql: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist
%sudo -u pgsql psql
psql: FATAL:  database "pgsql" does not exist
%sudo -u psql psql
sudo: unknown user: psql
%
```

How can I run PostgreSQL console? What's required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to template1 database and use pgsql user:

```
 # su pgsql
 $ psql template1
```

or

```
 $ sudo -u pgsql psql template1
```

Comment: I connected to default database `postgres` with command `sudo -u pgsql psql postgres`. Thanks!